# Modal position relative to the size of the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2

I have a todo list inside a v-for(or ng-repeat, as you wish), and in each one i want to have a delete modal. I am doing this modal by hand with js and css. The thing is, i want the position of the modal be relative to the list. 
For example, if i am at the first element of the list, i want the modal to appears at the top (in front of the fist element).
But if is the 10th element of the list, i want the modal to appears in front of the 10th element, not at the top in front of the fist element.

like is this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrnogueira/0twuem2s/7/

Does anyone has a clue about how i can do this?

html:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
      {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
      <button @click="deleteLeader(index, item)"> delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
 var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
    ]
  },
   methods: { 
           deleteLeader: function(index,item){
                    this.inventory.splice(index,1);
            }
           }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `$event` as parameter to your `deleteLeader` function, from there you can get the html element that's being referenced and get its position and assign it to a modal

something like this

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
    ]
  },
   methods: { 
           deleteLeader: function(index,item,event){              
              var m = document.getElementById("modal");
              
              m.style.display = "block";
              m.style.top = event.target.offsetTop + "px";
              m.style.left = event.target.offsetLeft + "px";
              //this.inventory.splice(index,1);
            }
           }
           
});
```

```css
#modal{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
      {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
      <button @click="deleteLeader(index, item,$event)"> delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="modal" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <button>Maybe</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how can i adapt your code if inside a table, not a list? Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrnogueira/0twuem2s/11/

Comment: I think the event.target is the button, but i don't know why does not work inside of a table. And many thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira make sure your `button` have `position: relative;` https://jsfiddle.net/0twuem2s/16/

Answer (score 1):

### Solution: absolute positoned modal with dynamic CSS properties

You could pass vue's `$event` as a parameter, take click position from there and then change `top` and `left` CSS properties of your absolutely positoned element (in your case the modal).

[image]

### The code

HTML:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
      {{ item.name }} - ${{ item.price }}
      <button @click="deleteLeader(index, item, $event)"> delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="modal" class="hidden">
    Hello, I'm a modal!
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
    ]
  },
   methods: { 
           deleteLeader: function(index,item,event){
                    // maybe at this point you'd want to rename this method's name
                    this.inventory.splice(index,1);

                    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
                    modal.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
                    modal.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
                    modal.classList.remove("hidden");
            }
           }

});
```

CSS:

```
#modal {
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

### Working example :

https://jsfiddle.net/t88Lom9a/2/

Comment: sorry, i think your fiddle is not working as in the video :/